# Fuctions: into, onto or both

Tags: functions

Determine whether each of the following functions, defined from $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z},$ is one-to-one, onto, or both. Explain your answers.

i) $f(x, y) = x^2 + 1$

ii) $g(x, y) = x + y + 2$

Having a lot of confusion with this question, any help will be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the first thing to do: write down the definitions of "one-to-one" and "onto".  Then try to apply the definitions to the examples.  (Show this as part of the question to avoid having the question closed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x,y)=x^2 + 1$ is neither one one nor onto.

Hint: $f(1,0)=2$ and $f(-1,0)=2$ but $(1,0)\neq(-1,0).$
Also $0\in\mathbb{Z},$ but there does not exist any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x,y)=0.$

Similarly, apply definitions to check for the second function.